# Tic Tac Toe vs Computer

Tags: java, loops, matrix, tic-tac-toe

For an assignment I was asked to create a [7] x [7] matrix, and a tic tac toe game vs a computer. Player is X and Computer is O. 
[1][1] is choice 1, [1][3] is choice 2, [1][5] is choice 3, [3][1] is choice 4, etc etc until choice 9.
I have done everything except create two boolean methods to pass through the player and computer methods to check if the space is already occupied.

I cannot seem to be able to create a while loop and if-statement that logically tells the computer once it generates a random number between 1 and 9, that if that number is already taken, generate another random number until that number has NOT been taken.

```
public static char[][] ComputerPlays(char[][] M)
{
    System.out.println("Computer selects grid position...");
    //  *** computer play code ***

    int x = (int)((Math.random() * 9)+1);
    if (x ==1)
    {
        while (occupied(M[1][1]) == true)
        {
            x = (int)((Math.random() *9)+1);      
        }
        if (occupied(M[1][1])== false)
        {
            M[1][1] = 'O';        
        } 
    }
    if (x ==2)
    {
        if (occupied(M[1][3])== true)
        {
            x = (int)((Math.random() *9) +1);
        }
        if (occupied(M[1][3])== false)
        {
            M[1][3] = 'O';
        }
    }
    while (x ==3)
    {
        if (occupied(M[1][5])== true)
        {
            x = (int)((Math.random() *9) +1);
        }
        if (occupied(M[1][5])== false)
        {
            M[1][5] = 'O';        
        }

    }
    while (x ==4)
    {
        if (occupied(M[3][1])== true)
        {
            x = (int)((Math.random() *9) +1);
        }
        if (occupied(M[3][1])== false)
        {
            M[3][1] = 'O';
        }
    }
    while (x ==5)
    {
        if (occupied(M[3][3])== true)
        {
            x = (int)((Math.random() *9) +1);
        }
        if (occupied(M[3][3])== false)
        {
            M[3][3] = 'O';
        }
    }
    while(x ==6)
    {
        if (occupied(M[3][5])== true)
        {
            x = (int)((Math.random() *9) +1);
        }
        if (occupied(M[3][5])== false)
        {
            M[3][5] = 'O';
        }
    }
    while(x ==7)
    {
        if (occupied(M[5][1])== true)
        {
            x = (int)((Math.random() *9) +1);
        }
        if (occupied(M[5][1])== false)
        {
            M[5][1] = 'O';
        }
    }
    while (x ==8)
    {
        if (occupied(M[5][3])== true)
        {
            x = (int)((Math.random() *9) +1);
        }
        if (occupied(M[5][3])== false)
        {
            M[5][3] = 'O';
        }
    }
    while (x ==9)
    {
        if (occupied(M[5][5])== true)
        {
            x = (int)((Math.random() *9) +1);
        }
        if (occupied(M[5][5])== false)
        {
            M[5][5] = 'O';
        }
    }
    return M;
}//end Computer Play
```

Comment: You need to find a way to remember which numbers were picked. A boolean array, hashmap, or arraylist (java.util) will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will reroll a new position, but will not re-check previously tested positions.

For example, when you roll 5, and it is occupied, you will re-roll, but you won't go back and re-check 1 to 4.  If the new roll *is* 1 to 4, nothing will be played.

You need to put both the roll and the check (of all positions) into the loop.  The actual play can be left out of the loop, after a valid position is (finally) rolled.

Here is an example I wrote free-hand (due to time constrain):

```
public static char[][] ComputerPlays( char[][] M ) {
   System.out.println("Computer selects grid position...");
   int pos, x, y;
   do {
      pos = (int)(Math.random() * 9); // Roll a new position.
      x = ( pos / 3 )*2 + 1;
      y = ( pos % 3 )*2 + 1;
   } while ( occupied( M[x][y] ) ); // Repeat as long as the position is occupied.
   M[x][y] = 'O';
   return M;
} //end ComputerPlays
```

An alternatively would be to keep a list of open positions, removing them from the list as they are gone, and only roll on the list.  This will remove the need to reroll.

Comment: Thank you, I had so many if statements that I had an extra 50+ lines of coded that was not needed and made it immensely harder to navigate through. I ended up using your same formula for x and y and applied it to the UserPlays method as well and just decremented it by 1 and now everything works perfectly.